# Angularjs state routing and keeping DOM Intact

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create single page application and  one use case is i have `details` page which can be  triggered from multiple `parent` pages, more like acting as `modal box` but without any `absolute` property. I was  checking how to `show/hide`  based on the state change from `parent`.

This is what i have done till now 
http://plnkr.co/edit/t34ES8lUihcypetHF0rp?p=preview

If you take a look when clicking `View Home` from `home` `DOM` is not removed while navigating to next state .

But if you are in `About` Page and click `View About`, DOM is getting removed.

How can we show/hide `ui-view`. if we are navigating to `different state with same url` ?

Answer (score 0):

The same url 
    url: '^/details/:id',
for both the states is the issue.

Try having a wrapper state say "details" and then in that state's controller you may redirect based on some parameter that tells wrapper state which state to go to.